# how to get admin user access level in magento?

Tags: magento, acl

Is there a way to know the access level of the current logged in user to see if the user is granted with "all" or "customized" access role?
i can get the user role data but i can't seem to understand/find the access level so that i can apply some logic to my code (collection).
`Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()->getRole()->getData();`
above statement prints: 
`Array
(
    [role_id] => 34
    [parent_id] => 0
    [tree_level] => 1
    [sort_order] => 0
    [role_type] => G
    [user_id] => 0
    [role_name] => Demo
    [gws_is_all] => 1
    [gws_websites] => 
    [gws_store_groups] => 
)`

how can i get the information here on access level (all, customized) of the assigned role to the user?

much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

solved it with help. here's my solution:

```
$role = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')
  ->getUser()
  ->getRole()
  ->getData();

$rule = Mage::getModel('admin/rules')
  ->getCollection()
  ->addFieldToFilter('role_id',$role['role_id'])
  ->getFirstItem()
  ->getData(); 
//see if the role has all access 
if ($rule['resource_id'] == 'all') {
   return $this;
}
```